# How do single-nozzle staged combustion rockets control roll?

Tags: engines, flight-control

Related: [How do single engine rockets control roll?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/how-do-single-engine-rockets-control-roll)

[image]

While many single-nozzle rockets are gas generator powered & can deflect the pump exhaust asymmetrically to produce a torque, staged combustion motors cannot. For rockets like Zenit and Atlas V, which have multiple nozzles, this is no problem. However, rockets using a *single nozzle* staged combustion engine, such as the Naro-1 & Angara (RD-191), Soyuz-2-1v (RD-193), and similar, how is roll control
provided?

Comment: I'll point you to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20755/how-does-a-single-srb-control-attitude). While the question was about attitude, the answer also addresses roll. Similar controls can be seen on one of the rockets you mentioned, the [Soyuz-2-1v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-2-1v), which use [RD-0110R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-0110R) as [Vernier thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_thruster).

Comment: A modified ***0110*** is used as veriners??? I need to see a diagram or something because I have NO clue how that would look. Did they just cut out the -0110 turbopump veriner system and weld it around the -193?

Comment: @neph https://www.kosmonavtika.com/lanceurs/soyouz/version/14A15/fig1-1.jpg

Comment: Angara uses thrusters.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angara_(rocket_family)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is ITAR.

Comment: @DavidHammen Angara and Soyuz?

Comment: @OrganicMarble new *SpaceForce!* policy

Comment: The problem with these kinds of questions is that one will not get a complete answer. ITAR, along with its equivalents in Europe, Russia, China, and India, is stupid in many ways, but there it is, and it is there, accompanied with threats of lengthy amounts of jail time.

Comment: @ikrase you **really don't** want to get into discussions of consitutionality in any thread on any site, let alone one dedicated to  the science of space exploration :-(

Comment: fwiu, V2 rocket engine even if open cycle, did not use pump exhaust at an angle to create rolling torque. Rather it used two pairs of graphite control vanes in the venturi, one pair for yaw, one for pitch. Roll used yaw vanes in phase opposition, like ailerons. In addition there was trim vanes on the fins, taking over roll control when fast enough